# How do I execute different SELECT statements based on a CASE

Tags: sql, sybase, case

I am facing a problem in executing queries with CASE statement.
Based on my condition,(for eg. length), I want to execute different SQL statement.

Problematic sample query is as follows:

```
select case 
    when char_length('19480821') = 8
        then select count(1) from Patient
    when char_length('19480821')=10
        then select count(1) from Doctor 
end
```

Exception:

> [Error] Script lines: 1-5 --------------------------
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>   Msg: 156, Level: 15, State: 2
>   Server: sunsrv4z7, Line: 2

I am not able to correct the syntax. I am getting the string for char_length as input from the user.
How can I fire queries based on certain condition?
Is CASE the right choice ? Or do I have to use any other thing.

Answer (score 8):

Just put opening and closing bracket around select statement resolve you problem

```
select 
    case when 
        char_length('19480821')=8 then 
            (select count(1) from Patient )
        when 
        char_length('19480821')=10 then 
            (select count(1) from Doctor )
      end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  case when char_length('19480821')=8 then (select count(1) from Patient)
        when char_length('19480821')=10 then (select count(1) from Doctor)
    end
```

The problem is that you are missing opening and closing brackets in your nested 'Select' statements :)

Comment: you might want to move the opening parentheses in the second then clause one word right.

Comment: still there is syntax error because in thrid line then is inside bracket

Answer (score 2):

Please do note that it is not a case STATEMENT, it is a case EXPRESSION.  By enclosing the queries in parentheses, you are converting them (syntactically) to values.

This is similar in principle to a subquery, such as 
"  select name from Doctor where salary = (select max(salary) from Doctor)"

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
  case when 
      LEN('1948082100')=8 then 
          (select 'HELLO' )
      when 
      LEN('194808210')=10 then 
          (select 'GOODBYE')
  end
```

Change the values to test results.