# Crystal Reports If Else in Database select SQL Command

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Im hoping to have have an if/else in my sql command within crystal 2013. The idea is something similar to this and I don't want to use stored procedures.

```
IF {?Search_Settings} = "This"
    THEN
    BEGIN (SELECT * FROM blah
           WHERE GETDATE() < blah.date)
    END

else if {?Search_Settings} = "That" 
    THEN
    BEGIN (SELECT * FROM blah
           WHERE GETDATE() > blah.date)
    END
```

As mentioned I am looking to have this in the database expert > Modify Command Screen.

Is this even possible? If not, what is the best option for achieving this? I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Why don't you put this in your Report > Select Expert > Record...

Comment: If I put it there I wont get my field names needed for the report. Im not pulling each field over manually using the wizard Im using the command to get them. And the actual sql Im using has many joins. I don't want an exact answer to figure out why my code isn't working, I need to know if the theory of what I want to do is even possible and if Im formatting it wrong what can I do to format it correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute different SELECT statements based on a CASE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163675/how-do-i-execute-different-select-statements-based-on-a-case)