# Syntax error when trying to next multiple select queries in a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

```
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE
           WHEN @field1 != '' 
              THEN (SELECT <some stuff>
                    FROM <table>
                    WHERE col1 = @field1 
                      AND col2 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@field2, -1) = -1 
                                         THEN col2 ELSE @field2 END)
           WHEN @field3 != '' 
              THEN (SELECT <some stuff>
                    FROM <table>
                    WHERE col3 = @field3)
       END
```

I've got the above start to a stored procedure. The idea is that there are multiple columns you can search on so most data is not present in a given search.  I'm trying to create different searches based on what parameters were passed with values. I took the general syntax for the above from one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163675/how-do-i-execute-different-select-statements-based-on-a-case) answers but I'm getting the following errors.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, also, if it matters, this is SQL Server 2017

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 20 [Batch Start Line 5]
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 5]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

EDIT: quick note that the first error references the parens before the second when statement

Comment: CASE is an expression used to determine which scalar value to return. IF is used to control flow. You should be using an IF statement here, not a case expression.

Comment: Learn how to use `CASE`.  `SELECT CASE WHEN...THEN SELECT ...` will definitely not work.

Comment: Thanks for the snark!  Please explain the answer in the referenced question.  That is what the most upvoted answer is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `IF` to select the query to return. By using `CASE`, you are returning scalar values instead of sets of data.  Something like this should work:

```
IF @field1 <> '' BEGIN
    select <some stuff>
    from <table>
    where col1 = @field1 and col2 = case when isnull(@field2,-1) = -1
        then col2 else @field2 end
END ELSE IF @field3 <> '' BEGIN
    select <some stuff>
    from <table>
    where col3 = @field3
END
```